# Decode JSON to NSArray or NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json

I hope to decode the JSON data below:

```
{
    "content":
    [   
        {
            "1":"a",
            "2":"b",
            "3":"c",
            "4":"d",
            "mark":"yes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure if put it in NSArray or NSDictionary

Welcome any comment

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

which iOS version are you using? in iOS 5 you have the `NSJSONSerialization` class to parse JSON data, if you need to target older iOSs or MAC OSX  you should use third parties lib such as `SBJSON`. The string posted will be a NSDictionary with an array with one dictionary. The array will be accessible using the key `@"content"`

In code:

```
NSString * jsonString = @"blblblblblb";
NSStringEncoding  encoding;
NSData * jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
NSError * error=nil;
NSDictionary * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

In SWIFT 2.0:

```
    let jsonString = "blblblblblb"
    let encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
    let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(encoding)
    guard let jData = jsonData else {return}
    do {
        let parsedData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jData, options: [])
    } catch let error {
        print("json error: \(error)")
    }
```

[UPDATE]
The `NSJSONSerialization` class is also available for 10.7 my comment wasn't correct.

Comment: Sorry the tag is objective c, by the way you used a class only available on iOS5 ;-)

Comment: Exactly, so it doesn't have to be iOS. `NSJSONSerialization` is also available in OS X 10.7.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is available in OS X 10.7

Answer (score 3):

That particular string will decode into an NSDictionary because the outermost thing is a JSON object which maps onto a NSDictionary for every JSON implementation I have ever seen.  If you want to process an arbitrary string, you'll need to test what you get back

```
NSError *jsonError;
id parsedThing = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
if (parsedThing == nil)
{
    // error
}
else if ([parsedThing isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
{
    // handle array, parsedThing can be cast as an NSArray safely
}
else
{
    // handle dictionary, parsedThing can be cast as an NSDictionary
    // NB only dictionaries and arrays allowed as long as NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
    // not specified in the options
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:` is deprecated in `iOS<6`

for `iOS 6+`

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contents" ofType:@"json"];
NSError * error=nil;
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:nil error:&error];
NSData * jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:nil];
NSArray * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

`contents.json` file is in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
NSData *data = ...; //JSON data
NSError *jsonError = nil;
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

You will get back an `NSDictionary` containing an `NSArray` containing a single `NSDictionary` containing five `NSString` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I used google speech recognition API and I was getting a json response which was not directly parsable on iOS. Results samples were like :

First I tried saying Hello 1 2 3 which was recognised without issues. Json response was :

```
{"result":[]}

{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"hello 123","confidence":0.59780568},{"transcript":"hello 1 2 3"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

Or when talked for too long, I got a 404 HTML like below :

```
<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>
```

And when I spoke gibberish , I got :

```
{"result":[]}
```

So to parse all such response, I used the below code :

```
 NSString *msg = @"Could not synthesize !";

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString: %@",responseString);
    if([responseString containsString:@"transcript"]&&responseString.length>25)
    {

        responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{\"result\":[]}" withString:@""];

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        if(dictionary!=nil)
            if(dictionary.allValues.count>0)
            {

                NSArray *array =[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"result.alternative.transcript"];

                if(array)
                {
                    NSArray *array2 = [array objectAtIndex:0];
                    if(array2)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"%@",[array2 objectAtIndex:0] );
                        msg = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
                    };
                }
            }
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Google Response" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: On prior to iOS8, the line     `if([responseString containsString:@"transcript"] && responseString.length>25)` should be changed to the following :
        
    `if ([responseString rangeOfString:@"transcript" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound && responseString.length>25)`