# How to convert NSData to NSMultableArray

Tags: ios, nsdata

I have a question how to conver NSData to NSMultableArray

I recive the data from JSON and I need to set that data into the Table View.
How to do that?

Above is the example of the JSON:

```
{"d":"[{\"codUf\":28,\"descricao\":\"MG\"},{\"codUf\":29,\"descricao\":\"PR\"},{\"codUf\":19,\"descricao\":\"RJ\"},{\"codUf\":25,\"descricao\":\"SP\"}]"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First you have to parse your data, at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can find out how. Then you can extract your array from it.

Comment: Parse it with any of several available JSON parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use SBJson https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

or else you can do

```
NSError *error = nil;
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSData *responseData = ...
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IOS 5 + you can NSJSONSerialization and if you are supporting older version as well you can use SBJSON.

This question might help you.

[Decode JSON to NSArray or NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121693/decode-json-to-nsarray-or-nsdictionary)