# How to make a dictionary of dictionaries in JSON?

Tags: ios, json, plist

Right now I have this structure in JSON

```
"Types":[  
            {  
               "LowCadence":[  
                  {  
                     "Reinforcement":"-1",
                     "Weight":"100",
                     "Message":"Pay attention. You're running low cadence. Your cadence is %d steps per minute."
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "NormalCadence":[  
                  {  
                     "Reinforcement":"0",
                     "Weight":"100",
                     "Message":"Great, your cadence is on target. Cadence is %d steps per minute.",
                     "EnforcementSound":"ding"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "HighCadence":[  
                  {  
                     "Reinforcement":"1",
                     "Weight":"100",
                     "Message":"Slow down. You're running over your planned cadence. Cadence is %d steps per minute."
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
```

But I would like it to have this structure

[image]

Does anyone know how to write it in JSON?

Comment: In JSON, the "correct" name for this thing seems to be "object", not "dictionary". https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your JSON would look something like:

```
var Types = {
    NormalHR: {
        Reinforcement: 0,
        Weight: 100,
        Message: 'Great! Your heart rate is in the zone.',
        EnforcementSound: 'ding'
    },
    HighHR: {
        Reinforcement: 1,
        Weight: 100,
        Message: 'Slow down. Your heart rate is too high!'
    },
    LowHR: {
        Reinforcement: -1,
        Weight: 100,
        Message: 'Speed up. Low heart rate.'
    }
};
```

As @Balder says in their answer, you can then access use dictionary-style syntax, like:

- `Types['NormalHR']['Reinforcement']`

You could also use property-accessor syntax, like:

- `Types.NormalHR.Reinforcement`

The reason I didn't include the "type" of each item, is that you can easily infer it for building your grid - as follows:

- `typeof Types.NormalHR.Reinforcement` (this will return `"number"`)
- `typeof Types.NormalHR.Message` (this will return `"string"`)

Similarly, to get the counts - you can count the properties of a specific object. In modern browsers, try:

- `Object.keys(Types.NormalHR).length` (this will return `2`)

For older browsers, refer to other methods here: [How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for you answer Troy, this is not for web, it's for iOS app

Answer (score 1):

You dont have "dictionaries" in json, but you have key/value arrays which works pretty much like them.

In your code if you want to access:

Normal Cadence > Message you only must do:

```
Types["NormalCadence"]["Message"]
```

Is similar to a .Net Dictionary, but is not exactly a Dictionary

Comment: I don't believe this will work, as you're using a property-style accessor to try and get a value out of an array.

Comment: Yes, because after json is proccess it becames an array in javascript

Comment: which language is that? Is it Swift? I'm using Objective-c...in the array JSON case, I have to parse this into a dictionary before I can use it, which is an overhead over the plist way..so I was curious if it's possible to mimic the same with JSON by formatting

Comment: Ahh - my answer may or may not help, then. Perhaps I misunderstood. Languages which serialize into / out of JSON handle dictionaries in their own way. I'm most familiar with .NET's serialization - which is based on how you declare the object serializer itself - and essentially just uses objects.

Answer (score 1):

In objective C you can write:

```
NSDictonary *types = @{
@"NormalHR": @{
    @"Reinforcement": [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
    @"Weight": [NSNumber numberWithInt:100],
    @"Message": @"Great! Your heart rate is in the zone.",
    @"EnforcementSound": @"ding"
},
@"HighHR": @{
    @"Reinforcement": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    @"Weight": [NSNumber numberWithInt:100],
    @"Message": @"Slow down. Your heart rate is too high!"
},
@"LowHR": @{
    @"Reinforcement": [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],
    @"Weight": [NSNumber numberWithInt:100],
    @"Message": @"Speed up. Low heart rate."
}
```

};

Comment: I need a JSON...so can pass it cross-platform

Comment: So the correct structure of needed json is the Troy Alford's one. If you need to serialize it into a NSDictonary take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10121757/1306216