# Retrofit generic response object with primitives

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

In iOS, responses don't need to be specifically encapsulated within an object. This allows for dynamic object returning, and you can just refer to the specific objects that you need ( see [Decode JSON to NSArray or NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121693/decode-json-to-nsarray-or-nsdictionary) ).  Is there an equivalent method in Android using retrofit?

To calrify if I had

```
"content":
  [   
    {
      "x":"1",
      "a":"b",
      "b":"c",
      "c":"d",
      "mark":"yes"
    }
  ]
```

I would get an object back where I could call object.x and get 1, or object.a and get b.  Where the key names could be any primitive object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a couple of assumptions. Assuming your are using retrofit 2 with a gson converter.  Also, your JSON is not valid, I am going to assume there is an enclosing object present --

```
{
  "content":
    [   
      {
        "x":"1",
        "a":"b",
        "b":"c",
        "c":"d",
        "mark":"yes"
      }
    ]
}
```

In Java, you want `Map`.  In your case, you'd have an array of `Map`'s. You can define your enclosing class as this --

```
public class Container {
    Map<String, Object> content[];
}
```

If you know that all your values are going to strings, you can use `Map<String, String>`, too.  You would use `Container` as your return type in your retrofit call.

```
@GET("/")
Call<Container> getSomething();
```

Assuming you put your result in variable named `container`, you can access the fields with `get`.

```
container.content[0].get("mark");
```

Note you'll want to add the appropriate null and bounds checks.