# how to convert this string to json or dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I tired with links but those are not working in my case.

Can anyone suggest me on how to convert this string to json or dictionary.

This string is having a dictionary with an array of strings.

```
NSString *temp=@"{\n    name =     {\n        dob = \"\";\n        age = \"61\";\n        family =         (\n                        {\n                location = location;\n                mobile = mobile;\n            }\n        );\n    };\n}";
```

Here family is an array.

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121693/decode-json-to-nsarray-or-nsdictionary

Comment: Santo check my ans if suits ..

Answer (score 11):

I got the solution.

First I tried your code

```
NSString *temp=@"{\n    name =     {\n        dob = \"\";\n        age = \"61\";\n        family =         (\n                        {\n                location = location;\n                mobile = mobile;\n            }\n        );\n    };\n}";
```

My out put result is

```
null
```

Then I changed the JSON format.

So now your code should be

```
NSString *strJson=@"{\"name\":{\"dob\":88,\"age\":61},\"family\" : [{\"location\":\"us\",\"mobile\":\"mobile\"}]}";
NSData *data = [strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonOutput = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonOutput);
```

The printed result is

```
{
 family =     (
            {
        location = us;
        mobile = mobile;
    }
);
name =     {
    age = 61;
    dob = 88;
};
}
```

You have to remember that when you convert string to json

```
\n must be \"value\"
= must be :
( must be [
number must be 100(or anything else)
```

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

[image]

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).

[image]

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

[image]

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
>   double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.

[image]

> A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal
>   and hexadecimal formats are not used.

[image]

Finally

> Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens. Excepting a few
>   encoding details, that completely describes the language.

I got this useful data [from this](http://json.org/)

Comment: Please, can you explain why 'family' key-value pair is printed before 'name', as you can see the 'name' is before 'family' in JSON string? I am asking this because I am facing this problem with my data having keys as Unicode characters(Hindi Language). After converting to JSON the keys are changing their orders. I have also noticed they are getting sorted on basis of their Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

using `NSJSONSerialization` class and its method `JSONObjectWithData` you can convert `string` to `dict` or `json`.

```
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
//                              OR
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"string: %@",json);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON string has invalid format. You can refer here to see the correct format (http://json.org/). You can check http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ see if it is working.

I tried to clean your JSON string manually.

1. Remove `\n`, `\`, and `;`
2. Replace `=` with `:`.
3. Add double quotes `""` for every string (e.g., from `name` to `"name"`).

Recheck again and after the format is valid then you can use @vaibhav answer to convert `NSString` to `NSDictionary`. Or see here [How do I deserialize a JSON string into an NSDictionary? (For iOS 5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-string-into-an-nsdictionary-for-ios-5)