# Xcode-9 OR iOS 11 - replacing double quote with \" not working

Tags: ios, ios10, ios11

As I am replacing the double quote with escape char as mentioned in below in code. The Same code works fine in iOS 10.x and not working in iOS 11.

```
NSString *searchStr = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];

NSString *searchInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"@type\": \"com.xyz.rest.find.SearchQuery\",\"value\": \"%@\"}", searchStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[searchInput dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Any leads will be appreciated !!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show some sample text

Comment: Trying to convert "Cool" into "\"Cool\"" to pass in post body.

Comment: just use json encoding bro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873257/how-to-convert-this-string-to-json-or-dictionary-in-ios

Comment: I think u didn't get the question, Please check updated code !!

Comment: @ThreeCoins: can pls check updated code !!!!

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: @ThreeCoins: When I search for "Cool"(with double quote) it should get value as "\"Cool\'" in iOS 10 whereas in iOS 11 it gets ""Cool"" which doesn't give expected results. 

Eg: 
iOS 10 :

Input search Str: “Cool”

NSString *searchStr = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];

o/p: “\“Cool\””

iOS 11:

NSString *searchStr = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];

o/p: “”Cool””

It’s not even replacing double quote with any other character.

Answer (score 2):

This may be because of smart punctuation introduced in iOS 11. Please check below link.

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/778otd/ios_11_no_longer_encodes_double_quotes_as_the/

Comment: Thanks kishan, it's issue of smart punctuation.

Comment: Welcome @BhaveshPatel.